# Deleting a SQL Entry containing *

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Somehow I have entered a  entry into my table that consists of '*-/'.

All of my knowledge on deleting it returns either:

> Incorrect syntax near '*'.

or

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '*-/' to data type
>   int.

```
delete * from st210 where stid = '*-/'
```

and a command to delete all that were not part of my set

eg;id is not (1,2,3,4)

Comment: Use the wildcard % in your statement around the *_/  like so %*_/%

Comment: Edit your question and add the SQL statements you tried.

Comment: Please show the command you used.

Comment: What is the data type of `stid`?  Is that the column where you're seeing the value `'*-/'`?  The error seems to indicate that it's an integer column, which couldn't contain that value.

Comment: it is varchar and not null

Comment: Are you sure stid is varchar and not null?  Try this:  select  * from st210 where stid  < 10

Comment: @Joemalpass has solved this for me in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE column_name = '%*-/%';
```

or

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE column_name like '%*-/%';
```

Comment: Tried this. Still getting incorrect syntax near '*'

Comment: If you're using % as a wildcard on varchar columns, shouldn't this read `WHERE column_name like '%*-/%';` ?

Comment: My sql knowledge is hodgepodge learn as I need it. I couldn't for the life of me remember the name "escape character" so I could search for it until right now. But your command @JOE solved this for me.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your column `stid` is a textual data type (text, ntext, nvarchar, etc), but you've got a bunch of text in there that look like numbers, and for whatever reason, SQL Server is seeing those values and doing some implicit conversion for you, then failing.  Try this...

```
DELETE 
     st210 
WHERE
     CONVERT(nvarchar(max), stid) = '*-/'
```

Forcing the explicit conversion should avoid whatever incorrect implicit conversion is biting you.  If this doesn't work, let me know and I'll retract the answer.